# Database will be used for statistics/charts/graphs. Table orginization the right way?

Tags: cakephp

This database will be used to log a users substance use. So a user will be able to input the date they did a certain substance, the actual substance and the amount of the substance done in that specific session.

Currently I only have 2 tables. users, and records. The records table has the following values;

record_id, substance, date_use, amount, user_id

Many substances will obviously be repeated by the same or by different users.

Is this the most optimal way to organize my data when keeping in mind that I will and plan to use this to create statistics? Any links on database orgnization tips?

Comment: If you are allowing the users to free form type the substance into a text field you are allowing for the potential to have many misspelled records that will be difficult to search on.  If you know the names of the possible substances in advance you may want to create another table of the substances and reference it via id.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will have a predetermined list and then allow users to request substances to be added to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want something along the lines of this:

Tables

- substances
- users
- substances_users

You'll want to use the [hasMany Through associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model).

Where 'substances_users' has a `user_id`, `substance_id`, and `date_used` field.

That way, you have a table of substances that you can manage to keep from having duplicates, and allow you to build statistics more easily.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but at the same time I don't get why. So instead of my current system where I just list the substance, I will have a substance_id field that will link with the 'substances' table with an id right?

Is the only point of that to reduce the amount of text stores on the database which will make it more efficient? Or are there other reasons?

Comment: Because keeping text data in a table allows for minor name inconsistencies, trouble producing usable data...etc etc.  If you have a substances table, you can also use things like "record_count" (and CakePHP's counterCache) to keep track of how many records for each substance...etc.  If those substances are just text in a row...  ...  yuck.  Bad db design imo.  Or easily find all users who have a record with X substance.  Just makes the entire thing SO much easier to manage, makes many different kinds of data much easier to pull...etc etc etc.

Comment: What if I can't have my substances be a predetermined list? 

For instance brands, you can list some of the top brands but to list all that exist will basically be impossible.

Comment: Then build a process to add it if it doesn't yet exist with a smart-field for the user entry (or something).

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks for the help! I have another question, shouldn't I just use a date_id and do the same thing i'm going to do with substance? Have it in a separate field because surely multiple people will use the same date.

Comment: 1) that's is a new question, 2) you should mark this as the answer if it was (and/or up-vote it if it was helpful) 3) no - you don't need to manage dates as a separate table - one reason, since you should only storing it in one way Y-m-d (or something) - no chance for poor formatting...etc etc.

Comment: I marked you as an answer, and couldn't upvote because i'm a new users and I need reputation to do so. Thanks for the response and that answered my question